# WordPress, cmb2: can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code fails to compile:

```
 <?php if(!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nf_maetadata_prefix_bicon', true))){?>
                  <p> <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nf_maetadata_prefix_bicon', true) ?>" width="100px"> </p>
                   <?php }else{?>
                      <spam class="text-white"><b><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nf_maetadata_prefix_bicontext', true); ?></b></spam>
                  <?php }?>
```

with an error like this:

> Can't use function return value in write context in
>   /var/www/html/dev.banmo120/sc/wp-content/themes/banmo120/erjianban.php
>   on line 26"

How do I fix it?

I'm using cmb2 metabox.

Comment: It's spaN not spaM and what is line 26?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely running PHP version 5.4 or older, because

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
>   result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

See the [documentation for `empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function.

So, in PHP 5.4 (and older) you have to examine the result with a [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
if (false != get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nf_maetadata_prefix_bicon', true)))
```

or just rely on the implicit conversion to [`bool`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

```
if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nf_maetadata_prefix_bicon', true)))
```

P.S.: consider using the identity operator.